# "Proof" that $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ by using index laws. Why is this wrong?

Tags: arithmetic, absolute-value, fake-proofs

This is a very short argument that I have often seen about the definition of $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I'm not quite sure what is the flaw in this argument below, can someone please illustrate at what line this goes wrong and reference what "restriction" was broken from the original index law.

**Claim:** $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof:** Note that $$\begin{align*} \sqrt{x^2} &= (x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\ &= x^{\frac{2}{2}} \\ &= x^{1}=x.\end{align*}$$

What is wrong with this?

Comment: In general, $(a^b)^c\ne a^{bc}$.

Comment: Note that fractional powers are not nicely behaving for negative numbers.

Comment: $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt1=1\neq-1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First the counterexample to this is $x = -1$.
Now to the error in your reasoning is the following $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ is only true if $a \geq 0$.

Comment: @Q the Platypus Thanks that makes sense

Comment: @Q the Platypus
Sorry just a follow up question, about the "only true" part
$((-2)^2)^3=64=(-2)^6$ but $-2$ is not positive. Do you mean it is only true for non-integer but rational powers when $a\ge 0$?

Comment: if you take the sixth root of 64, you get 2 not -2 because it's nearly always assumed you want the positive version.